# Importing class from the main script creates a duplicate of that class?

Tags: python, class, singleton, python-import

I'm quite new to python and I'm working on an application with singleton classes (I know what people say about singletons, but they're suitable for my needs), but  I encountered a problem which isn't caused by the singletons but does prevent them from working properly.

Consider this code (which doesn't involve singletons):
**main.py**

```
class Test:
    pass

def main():
    print("main.py:", Test, id(Test))
    import test

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**test.py**

```
from main import Test

print("test.py:", Test, id(Test))
```

results:

```
main.py: <class '__main__.Test'> 1382824602424  
test.py: <class 'main.Test'> 1382824594872
```

It looks like the `Test` class in *main.py* is **not** the same as the one in *test.py* (they have different name and id), so the `Test` class was duplicated when imported in *test.py*?

note: I tried that with `import main` and `main.Test` instead - same results.

This strange behavior of python actually prevents my implementation of singletons from working correctly.

Here's the singleton metaclass implementation:

```
from collections import defaultdict

# A `defaultdict` subclass which passes the missing key
# as an argument to `default_factory`
class KeyDefaultDict(defaultdict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        if self.default_factory is None:
            raise KeyError(key)
        res = self[key] = self.default_factory(key)
        return res

class Singleton(type):
    # a dictionary that maps between the singleton class
    # and the singleton object of that class. When attempting
    # to access the singleton object for the first time (via
    # the `instance` property), the object will be created and
    # added to the dictionary (lazy initialization).
    __instances = KeyDefaultDict(type.__call__)

    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, dct):
        # prevent inheritance from a singleton class
        for base in bases:
            if isinstance(base, mcs):
                raise TypeError("Singletons can't be inherited from")
        return super().__new__(mcs, name, bases, dct)

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        raise TypeError("Singletons can't be instantiated")

    @property
    def instance(cls):
        try:
            return cls.__instances[cls]
        except TypeError as e:
            # happens when the singleton class `__init__` method
            # has more parameters than just self
            raise TypeError("Singletons can't be instantiated "
                            "with parameters") from e
```

and a simple usage example that proves that the singleton works:

```
class MySingleton(metaclass=Singleton):
    def __init__(self):
        print("Initialized")  # will be printed once
        self.x = 5

s1 = MySingleton.instance  # "Initialized" printed
s2 = MySingleton.instance
assert s1 is s2, "Singleton failed"
assert s1 is MySingleton.instance, "Singleton failed"
print(s1.x, s2.x, MySingleton.instance.x)  # output: 5 5 5
MySingleton.instance.x = 10
print(s1.x, s2.x, MySingleton.instance.x)  # output: 10 10 10
```

With this implementation, it's critical that the class doesn't change, so its key stays the same in the `__instances` dictionary. However, in the example above, if I made the `Test` class singleton, `Test.instance` would result in **different** objects in *main.py* and *test.py*, since they're "different" classes (different id).  In other words, I get two **different** keys in `__instances`: one for *main.py* and one for *test.py*, of the same class `Test` which results in two different objects of the singleton class.

After searching on the internet, I found that this is the best implementation of the singleton pattern in python (in my opinion), so I'd prefer not to change that, but to change or work around the strange behavior of python instead.

Can you please explain to me why is python treating the `Test` class like this in the different files, and more importantly, how to change that behavior or work around it, so the `Test` class will be the same in the main script and in any external python script?

Note: I'm using python 3.6.5 on Windows 10.

Comment: Yeah, that happens when you try to treat the same file as a script and a module. `__main__` is treated as a separate module from what you imported. It's one of the really weird parts of Python's module system.

Comment: It's simplest to just keep scripts and modules separate. If you really want to mix up the concepts, then avoiding circular imports will avoid the situations where the same file could end up as two modules.